# How come my function is only looping through three elements within my list

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to loop through all the elements (8 of them) in my list, but my function is only providing me with 4 of them. This is for an application I am making as a personal project.

```
import urllib


def get_followers():
    count = 0
    link = ['http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=beratmahmuzlu',     'http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=lidiazuin', 'http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=kelewele_boham', 'http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=AwangHafizam', 'http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=BRAYANLVN', 'http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=zezol_pl', 'http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=brysonwong', 'http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=racsozara']
    while count < len(link):
        print link[count]
        link.pop()
        count = count + 1
```

Comment: please indent your code, it is crucial since it is python.

Comment: Wait, what's urllib got to do with this?

Comment: If the simple for loop is not what you want, you'll have to explain more. What are you _trying_ to achieve with `link.pop()`

Answer (score 9):

You are popping the list and basing your loop off of the count of the list.

try a for loop instead:

```
for lnk in link:
    print lnk
```

Answer (score 3):

link.pop() removes an element and len(link) gives you the new length of the list at each iteration, looping thus thru only the half of your list.

```
def get_followers():
    count = 0
    link = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    l = len(link)
    while count < l:
        print link.pop()
        count = count + 1
```

This is the correct implementation, although there are many more cleaner way to iterate over a list in python, this is one of the simplest:

```
def get_followers():
    link = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    for l in link:
        print l
```

Comment: Did you **try** the first one? Just caching the list length doesn't help, because the list is still getting modified (popped from the end). Now the code raises an exception as well as only printing the first half of the elements.

Comment: You're right, too much copy&paste there. Should work now. And no, I've not tried it.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to loop through all the elements (8 of them) in my list

Then do that. Don't set up a counter variable, repeatedly use it to index into the list, remove elements from the list and increment the counter. Just loop through the elements.

If I asked you to crack a dozen eggs, you would not need to write numbers on them, or think about how many eggs you'd already cracked. You'd just do it.

So just do it.

```
for link in links:
    print link
```